# Trouble suming totals

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Have trouble adding a summary for columns number, square and cube for totals. Any pointers where I should be looking at? Below is copy of my code.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number;
            int total = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("number\t" + "square\t" + "cube");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");

            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i += 2)
            {
                number = i;
                int k = 0;
                do
                {
                    Console.Write(number + "\t");
                    number *= i;
                    total += number;
                    k++;

                } while (k < 3);

                Console.WriteLine("Total is",total);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want correctly, one way to do this is to keep track of the running totals for each power (1, 2, and 3) in an array, and then display those values at the end.

The array would have 3 indexes, and each time we increase the 'power' that we're raising our number to, we add that value to the corresponding index in the array.

For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // This array will hold three items:
    //  - totals[0] = numberTotal
    //  - totals[1] = squareTotal
    //  - totals[2] = cubeTotal
    var totals = new int[3];

    Console.WriteLine("number\t" + "square\t" + "cube");
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");

    for (int number = 0; number <= 20; number += 2)
    {
        // Grab a copy of 'number' so we don't modify the loop variable
        var thisNumber = number;

        for(int powerIndex = 0; powerIndex < 3; powerIndex++)
        {
            // Write this number to screen
            Console.Write($"{0:n0}\t", thisNumber);

            // Add this number to the current number in 'power' index
            totals[powerIndex] += thisNumber;

            // Power up
            thisNumber *= number;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("{0:n0}\t{1:n0}\t{2:n0}\t", totals[0], totals[1], totals[2]);

    // Alternatively, if you're using C#6.0, you could write:
    Console.WriteLine($"{totals[0]:n0}\t{totals[1]:n0}\t{totals[2]:n0}\t");

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what looking for summing totals. Only issue is the cube are calculated incorrectly since it should be going 0,8,64,216,512 giving total of 24,200. Believe it has something to do with second loop.

Comment: Ah, you're right...I used the wrong variable when powering up! Fixed it above...

Comment: If I wanted to put comma for values in thousands, wouldn't this work below?  Console.Write("{0,8:n0}", thisNumber + "\t");

Comment: Yeah, not sure you need the `,8`, but I updated the example above. If you're using C# 6.0, you can also use string interpolation: `Console.Write($"{thisNumber:n0}\t");`

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code:

First one is about Console.WriteLine. To get it working you should pass parameters as for example shown here (it's not the only way to do it but it's the simplest)

```
Console.WriteLine("Total is" + total);
```

Secon one is more about algorithm. Let's check when you are adding number to total. If you look closer you can see that you are not adding same number, which you displayed, but your adding number * i ! Thats big mistake but to fix it just swap that two lines like that:

```
Console.Write(number + "\t");
total += number;
number *= i;
k++;
```

I belive that fixes every issue, hope it helps :-)

Full code:

```
using System;

namespace Sum
{
   public class Program
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           int number;
           Console.WriteLine("number\t" + "square\t" + "cube");
           Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");

           for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i += 2)
           {
               number = i;
               int total = 0;
               int k = 0;
               do
               {
                   Console.Write(number + "\t");
                   total += number;
                   number *= i;
                   k++;
               } while (k < 3);
               Console.WriteLine("Total is "+total);
               Console.WriteLine();
           }

           Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but doesn't seem to work. For each column have number, square, and cube. It outputs the correct numbers and the end of the table it has to sum up the total for each of them.

Comment: Yeah, sorry man i think i didn't get concept of what you are looking for :-)